# Passing a file location to python

Tags: python

I am completely new to Linux and Ubuntu.

I have written python code in Windows and want to run it in Ubuntu. It uses a text file for input. The 'path-to-file' in windows looks as follows

```
c:user\documents\python\file.txt
```

How is the location written for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Rather than hardcoding paths in your Python script we should make use of the [path operation from the module os](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).

**os.path.expanduser(*path*)** expands the path to the user's home directory
**os.path.join(*path1*,*path2*,...)** joins path elements with the appropriate separator
**os.sep** gives the OS dependent path separator (`/` for Linux/Unix, `\` for Windows)
**os.getcwd()** gives the current working directory
**os.path.abspath(path)** gives the OS dependent absolute path of a given path

Example:

```
>>>import os
>>>path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'documents', 'python', 'file.txt')
>>>print (path)
```

Result

```
/home/user/documents/python/file.txt ## when on Ubuntu
C:\Users\user\documents\python\file.txt ## when running Windows
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have permission to add comments...so I will just try to answer.

The path at UNIX will be like: `/home/user/file.txt`

When you at any folder and want to get the absolute path of a file, you could use the `readlink` command:

```
readlink -f file.txt
```

example at our server:

```
$ readlink -f format.log 
/home/dli/format.log
```

Answer (score 1):

File paths are written as-

```
/path/to/file
```

Everything in your home folder is located inside `/home/username/`

So, if you have a file on your desktop, it is located in `/home/username/Desktop/`

Other partitions are mounted in `/media` by default.

If you directly want to get the path of a file, you can copy the file, and paste it into your text editor, this should give you the path to your file. Put a \ before every space in the path to 'escape' the space. e.g. `/media/myuseraccount/Desktop/an awesome file` would be written as:

```
/media/myuseraccount/Desktop/an\ awesome\ file
```

Another thing to note is that in Linux, your file names are case sensitive, so 'desktop' is not the same as 'Desktop'.

Finally, a shortcut to your home folder is to type `~`

So, you can access your desktop by typing:

```
~/Desktop
```

and you can access your home folder by typing:

```
~/
```